# Is there a way to start on a specific row using Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I am using ACF (advanced custom fields) in Wordpress. I have about 40 rows to display but I would like to start on row 5. Basically I want to display row 5 on down to 40 instead of starting on row one. Is there a way to do this? My code is below.

```
          <?php




          if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
          $i = 0;

            // loop through the rows of data
              while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();

              $i++;


            if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) {

                the_sub_field('feature_article_link'); 
                the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
                the_sub_field('feature_title'); 

            } 

              if( $i > 40 )
              {
                break;
              }


              endwhile;

          else :

              // no rows found

          endif;

          ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use continue statement in your loop to skip iterations as below :

```
<?php
      if( have_rows('repeat_field') ):
      $i = 0;
        // loop through the rows of data
          while ( have_rows('repeat_field') ) : the_row();
          $i++;
          if($i<5)
              continue;
          if (!empty(get_sub_field('feature_image_post'))) 
          {
              the_sub_field('feature_article_link'); 
              the_sub_field('feature_image_post'); 
              the_sub_field('feature_title'); 
          } 
          if( $i > 40 )
          {
              break;
          }
          endwhile;
      else :
          // no rows found
      endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. This was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using code like this:

```
<?php

$repeat = get_field('repeat_field');

for ($i = 5; $i <= 40; $i++) {

    if (!empty($repeat[$i]['feature_image_post'])) {

        echo $repeat[$i]['feature_article_link']; 
        echo $repeat[$i]['feature_image_post']; 
        echo $repeat[$i]['feature_title'];         

    } 

}

?>
```

Just use `get_field` to get an array of your repeater and then use the `for` function in PHP to loop through the 5th to the 40th